# Remote shutdown

Tags: shutdown, remote

I am running an Ubuntu workstation with apache2 on it.  I want to be able to submit a shutdown command remotely to Ubuntu from another machine when the other system senses a power failure (while still on battery).

How can I do this?

Comment: Why not just have the machine shut itself off? It would be a lot simpler.

Answer (score 0):

The apache2 Ubuntu is running on a laptop, isn't it?
So when the laptop have its battery lower than a fixed value, you want to be notified so you can shut it down?

So you have three steps:

1. Monitoring battery and detecting the value (trigger)

   - You can use APCUPSD for monitoring and sending notification using email
   - you'll need postfix or any MTA local server/sender
2. Send the notification

   - you can use email triggered by the point 1 using monitoring software such as webmin for example or the monitoring software features, or use a script with `batmon` and `notify-osd`.
3. issue the command

   - If the command is manual a simple SSH command would be enough: `ssh user@ip 'command to send'`
   - The command to send could be a script in the user local directory.

Comment: please could you elaborate on these suggestions so OP can achieve what they want using only your answer?